# Classification of Blackberry devices by using useragent

Tags: javascript, blackberry, user-agent

I need to classify blackberry devices based on OS version.

if BB5 and BB6 then {do this}

if BB7 and above then {do this}

I knew,
BB 5 useragent looks like this :

**BlackBerry9700/5.x.x.x Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/229**

BB 6 onward useragent is :

**Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9800; zh-TW) AppleWebKit/534.1+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.x.x.x Mobile Safari/534.1+**

So, How can i classify 5&6 and 7&above?

Comment: I've come back to this Question to follow up on. If my answer here is satisfactory, please Accept this answer so this question is resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The open source **Detect Mobile Browsers** script may be what your looking for.

When visiting that webpage, which also contains the links to download the script in a plethora of formats, it will show you the relevant information via a live example.

On my desktop PC which isn't a mobile device, I receive this info:

**No mobile browser detected.**
**Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0**

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

*P.S. If you do use that script note Boolean **true** or **false** on the variable is to be used (i.e., use **!!** before variable name to test for false).*

Here is jsfiddle example that I completed so you can test with your Blackberry Device.
http://jsfiddle.net/sPBrL/4/