# Differentiating between portrait mode on handheld devices and desktops

Tags: javascript, css, less, media-queries

I'm looking for a reliable media query rule that is:

```
If desktop width < 720px AND devices in portrait mode {}
```

(that is, as the width decreases on desktop, the media query kicks in at 720px. On phones, this should only happen when it is in portrait mode - landscape should not have the media query applied)

---

**The problem is: how to target devices separately from desktops.**

**Problem exists because: `@media handheld` is not supported**

**Additionally `max-width` effects everything, so it can't be used in conjunction with `max-device-width AND portrait`**

---

Seems like I can only target either:

1. all devices bellow/between set widths
2. only devices (using a JavaScript shim to fix media queries) bellow/between set widths and orientation.

CANNOT treat devices and desktops separately.

Is there an existing JavaScript solution which would fulfill my needs?

**note** I am coding my CSS in LESS, the media queries are nested within.

---

**Background**

The site I am working on is responsive and uses a grid system. At 720px width (current testing width) column usage changes for smaller devices / resolutions. Upon testing, however, the site (full site at 720px width) was pleasantly readable in landscape, even on my small screen HTC Desire. As I am removing portions of the site for better usability with media queries, I thought why not have the site normally accessible in landscape.

Bellow 720px on a desktop without modifying element column spans sees a pretty crushed site. However, due to the smaller nature of a mobile device it doesn't appear so. However with the column span modifications, particular elements are simply out of proportion (such as the heading) when it comes to landscape on a phone (due to the much reduced height of the browser).

Simply put, changing the design purely on browser width doesn't carry across all devices equally, as I have managed to achieve on other sites.

I am using the following meta tag:

```
<meta  name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, 
    initial-scale=1, 
    maximum-scale=1, 
    user-scalable=no" />
```

---

**What's been tried**

Orientation is irrelevant on desktops. It changes depending on user window settings, resolution, etc etc.

I have tried the following to target phones/both:

```
@media handheld and (orientation:portrait) { }
```

No phones it seems take advantage of the `handheld` attribute, at least, 100% do not - so it's worthless.

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:720px) and (orientation:portrait)  { }
```

Would work great, but android 2.2 and 2.3 (possibly others, not to mention other OS?) have issues with `max-device-width` not working.

```
@media screen and (max-width:720px) and (orientation:portrait)  { }
```

Works on high res monitors (since height quickly becomes > width as you decrease width of the window) and phones, but wont work on smaller monitors, as the windows wont be portrait at 720px width (site keeps condensing past the limits I want).

```
@media screen and (max-width:720px), screen and (orientation:portrait)  { }
```

Will do whatever comes first. No use.

```
@media screen and (max-width:720px), screen and (max-width:500px) and (orientation:portrait) { }
```

and

```
@media screen and (max-width:720px) { }
@media screen and (max-width:500px) and (orientation:portrait)  { }
```

Everything simply uses the larger `max-width`.

I've also had a fiddle with `min/max-height` with no success either.

Comment: Just a forethought. But all modern handhelds have html5 standard. So if the device doesn't support a css3 prop, then it's probably a desktop

Answer (score 5):

I think the best method is, according to MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) using `window.innerHeight` documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.innerHeight) and `window.innerWidth` documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.innerWidth) where it measures the *browsers* width and height in pixals to determine the orientation.

```
//Detect mobile platform

var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};

if ( isMobile.any() ) {

    if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
       console.log("Orientation is in portrait");
       }
    else {
       console.log("Orientation is in landscape");
         }
    }
else {
   console.log("Mobile platform not detected.");
};
```

More documentation here for [mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/api/events.html) platforms.

Comment: +1 Although thought this would be an excellent starting point, it's better to use the **Detect Mobile Browser** JavaScript plugin, which is very lightweight and powerful. More on that in this [**SO Answer w/ jsFiddle DEMO**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10577801/1195891). Cheers!

Comment: Now how do I go from this point - being able to detect mobile devices with JavaScript - to being able to make a responsive site on desktops using media queries and max-width, and ignoring this rule when mobile portrait is detected? To make it more difficult, I'm coding in LESS, and the media queries are nested : D

Comment: @Patrick: to answer your question, I think the easiest would be to have the javascript upon detection add a class to the `body` tag (like `mobPort`), then have your media queries have what they do qualified in their css selector string with `body:not(.mobPort) ...[your other selectors]` so that when it detects that class, it does _not_ apply the media query changes.

Comment: @Patrick: In addition to ScottS comment, you can see this [**SO Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2568915/1195891) that shows how to select `metatags` based on conditional settings, and adapt that process using `LESS`.

Comment: Good idea @ScottS, though I'll need to look into older desktop browser compatibility...

Comment: @Patrick: Any browsers not supporting CSS3 will fail since `:not()` is CSS3, but I don't think non-CSS3 browsers support media queries anyway (IE8 and under).

Comment: Added an answer below detailing how to get @ScottS explanation to work in the context of nested LESS.

Answer (score 1):

Well these three rules cover most mobile devices

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px)
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px)

Alternatively try using the Skeleton Responsive framework

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). It includes feature detection/inference for virtually all useful modern browser features, notably including whether the device is touch-based via a simple Boolean check on `Modernizr.touch`. From there, you may be able to get away with testing for portrait/landscape by comparing document.width to document.height, something like:

```
if(Modernizr.touch) {
    // is touch device

    if(document.height > document.width) {
        // is in portrait
    } else {
        // is in landscape
    }
} else {
    // not touch device
}
```

Note that, as you've discovered, there is no perfect test for touch/desktop, so if you incorporate the Modernizr touch test (or roll your own), it would be good to consult this [page that explains which touch tests are reliable, when](http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/touch.html).

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, this is to explain how to use CSS selectors to qualify the use of media queries in the context of nested LESS.

@enginefree's answer, and the following comments, explained how to check for a mobile device, it's orientation and to manipulate an elements attributes based upon the result.

The following code illustrates how to use the LESS `&` and CSS3 `:not` selectors to display our media queries when the attribute or class we are looking for is **not** detected:

```
body {
    /* this has the possible class or data attribute of 'mobile' */
    /* this is not included in the nest as you can't climb at will */
    /* the class or attribute (via our JavaScript) could be applied
       to any element that sits above and outside of `#level-1` in 
       this example */

}


#level-1 { 

    #level-2 {

        #level-3 {

            #level-4 {

                body:not(.mobile) & {

                    /* produces the following CSS */
                    /* body:not(.mobile) #level-1 #level-2 #level-3 #level-4 { } */
                    /* rules in this block will only be executed if body does not have a mobile class */

                    @media screen and (max-width:) {

                    }
                }

                body:not([data-device=mobile]) & {

                    /* produces the following CSS */
                    /* body:not([data-device="mobile"]) #level-1 #level-2 #level-3 #level-4 { } */
                    /* rules in this block will only be executed if body does not have a mobile data-device attribute */

                    @media screen and (max-width:) {

                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

If the `body` element was part of this nest, you would end up with the following CSS, and this should explain why the element must exist out of the scope of the nest, as well as above it:

`body:not(.mobile) body #level-1 #level-2 #level-3 #level-4 { }`

[Read more about the `&` operator](http://lesscss.org/#-nested-rules)

Answer (score 0):

A great javascript library is [css3-mediaqueries-js](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/).